# Socket.io ionic 4 and php

Tags: php, ionic-framework, socket.io, chat, ionic4

I have configured my ionic 4 app with socket.io and followed the instructions on the socket.io website. Everything is working well on localhost because when I type `node index.js` at the command line the server socket.io starts and all users in the same network can chat in the same room.

How do I configure things so that it will work on an online server? Like configuration php?

Comment: you can use `https://www.heroku.com/` hosting for NodeJs. its simple and free. you just have to replace your localhost link with your generated heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a set up. I have it in almost all of my apps. Here it goes:

First of all, you need redis and node installed on the server.

Now, to trigger notification from the server, create a helper:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class SocketIo
{
    public static function trigger($event, $data)
    {
        $redisChannel = 'socket-io';
        $redis->publish($redisChannel, json_encode([
            'event' => $event,
            'data' => $data
        ]));
    }
}
```

Where `$redis` is your redis client. If you are using Laravel, you can set `$redis = app('redis');`

Now, create a simple node file, say `socket.js`, to actually handle socket-io:

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var socket = require('socket.io')(server);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
require('dotenv').config();

var redisChannel = process.env.SOCKET_IO_CHANNEL || 'socket-io';

redis.subscribe(redisChannel);
redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    socket.emit(message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node server is running socket.js on port 3000');
});
```

In your `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "ioredis": "^3.1.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
}
```

Of course, run `npm install` to install the dependencies and then you can go `node socket.js` to run it.

On production, you need to install something like `pm2` or `supervisor` to keep `socket.js` running all the time.

```
pm2 start socket.js
```

If you want to go with supervisor, here's the config:

```
[program:socket-io]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=node /var/www/express-callback/socket.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile=/var/www/express-callback/storage/logs/socket-io.log
```